# Como armazenar os resultados de operações em um dataframe no R

Tags: r, loop, dataframe

Estou tentando criar um código para armazenar a média e o intervalo de confiança para 4 parâmetros em um único data frame.

Seguem as primeiras 50 linhas do meu banco (o original tem 45.000 linhas)

```
   V1 V2    V3          V4
1  -1 -1 60060  0.00000000
2   1  5     1 -0.06785905
3   1  6     1  0.04155906
4   1  7     1 -0.05799888
5   1  8     1  0.01528183
6  -1 -1 60120  0.00000000
7   1  5     1 -0.06642739
8   1  6     1  0.04104612
9   1  7     1 -0.05768697
10  1  8     1  0.01462305
11 -1 -1 60180  0.00000000
12  1  5     1 -0.06999796
13  1  6     1  0.04367484
14  1  7     1 -0.04909942
15  1  8     1  0.01143046
16 -1 -1 60240  0.00000000
17  1  5     1 -0.07247141
18  1  6     1  0.04555364
19  1  7     1 -0.05317570
20  1  8     1  0.01240738
21 -1 -1 60300  0.00000000
22  1  5     1 -0.07896708
23  1  6     1  0.04835469
24  1  7     1 -0.05341820
25  1  8     1  0.01306940
26 -1 -1 60360  0.00000000
27  1  5     1 -0.08035722
28  1  6     1  0.04857349
29  1  7     1 -0.04655472
30  1  8     1  0.00885978
31 -1 -1 60420  0.00000000
32  1  5     1 -0.08256990
33  1  6     1  0.04995481
34  1  7     1 -0.04660467
35  1  8     1  0.00893150
36 -1 -1 60480  0.00000000
37  1  5     1 -0.08441984
38  1  6     1  0.05268727
39  1  7     1 -0.04825745
40  1  8     1  0.01034393
41 -1 -1 60540  0.00000000
42  1  5     1 -0.08277602
43  1  6     1  0.05012731
44  1  7     1 -0.05665450
45  1  8     1  0.01465027
46 -1 -1 60600  0.00000000
47  1  5     1 -0.08373034
48  1  6     1  0.05078569
49  1  7     1 -0.05891148
50  1  8     1  0.01507060
```

Eu preciso calcular a média e o intervalo de confiança para os parâmetros 5, 6, 7 e 8 da coluna V2. Os resultados são apresentados na coluna V4. Estava tentando trabalhar um loop e ele até gera o resultado correto, mas a rodada seguinte sobrescreve a anterior e só consigo armazenar o último resultado.

Meu loop é o seguinte:

```
for (i in 5:8) {
  trait <- i
  mean <- mean(data$V4[data$V2 == i])
  low_q <- quantile(data$V4[data$V2 == i], probs = 0.025)
  high_q <- quantile(data$V4[data$V2 == i], probs = 0.975)
  table <- data.frame(trait, mean, low_q, high_q)
}
```

Sendo data o nome do data frame que armazena o banco de dados

O resultado que eu busco é o seguinte:

```
trait    mean   low_q   high_q 
    5  -0.077  -0.084   -0.067
    6   0.047   0.041    0.052
    7  -0.053  -0.059   -0.047
    8   0.012   0.009    0.015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu exemplo, uma opção que simplifica o cálculo é utilizar o pacote `data.table`. Talvez não seja necessário utilizar o "loop".

Assumindo que os dados que você disponibilizou estão em um `dataframe` "dt":

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

dt2 <- dt[ V2 %in% 5:8, # filtra as linhas de interesse
          .(mean = mean(V4), # cálculo da média e quantis
            lowq = quantile(V4, probs = 0.025),
            highq = quantile(V4, probs = 0.975)),
          by = (trait = V2) ] # agrupa pela variável "V2"
```

Resultado:

```r
> dt2
   trait        mean         lowq       highq
1:     5 -0.07695762 -0.084264702 -0.06674951
2:     6  0.04723169  0.041161532  0.05225941
3:     7 -0.05283620 -0.058706145 -0.04656596
4:     8  0.01246682  0.008875917  0.01523430
>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Funcionou super bem! Vai me poupar um tempo enorme aqui =D

Comment: Que bom!! Esse pacote é bem útil para manipulação de dados. Especialmente quando se procura eficiência nos cálculos e no uso dos recursos da máquina